# Pass object to graphql query with Axios

Tags: typescript, axios, graphql, nestjs

so I want to pass an object as argument to graphql server using axios, here is my query

```
const query = `
  query SalesPropertySearch($source: Source!, $searchParameter: SearchParameter!) {
    salesPropertySearch(
          source: $source,
          searchParameter: $searchParameter
      ) {
          edges {
              id
              score
              projectName
          }
      }
  }`
```

then I'm making a request like:

```
const data = await lastValueFrom(
        this.httpService
            .post<GQLResponse<SalesPropertyApiResult>>('graphql', { query, variables: dto })
            .pipe(map(res => res.data.data.salesPropertySearch))
    )
```

the **dto** object looks like:

```
{
  source: 'CONDOMINIUM',
  searchParameter:{
    buildingNumber: '10',
    page: 1,
    perPageSize: 10
  }
}
```

so it is valid, but I still get a bad request error, seems like axios is passing the object within searchParameter a wrong way, is there any way to fix this?

same happens if I just pass query like this:

```
query { rentalPropertySearch(source:${dto.source}, searchParameter:${JSON.stringify(dto.searchParameter)}){
          edges {
              id
              score
          }
      }
  }
```

`

in this case axios adds  \\ characters,

please suggest how to fix this or how to properly pass object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

posting an update here: the issue was in the wrong query parameters (case sensitive values), no actual axios issue